# set to contain all numbers that can't be written with a finite number of digits

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm sorry if this was already asked/answered trough some different name, but I just couldn't find anything related to it nor here nor after a Google search.
It might also be because my native language isn't English and my thus my notions of maths in foreign languages is very limited.
Anyways, I'd like to know if there is a way to describe a set (I hope that is the proper word for it) that has all the numbers that can't be written with a finite number of digits (like $\sqrt{2}$, but also $\pi$ or $\dfrac13$).

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean numbers that do not admit a terminating decimal expansion? Those are all reals not of the form $n/2^a5^b$ for some integers $n,a,b$ with $a,b\ge0$.

Comment: You've just described it! Possibly, to write it down: $\{x\in\mathbb R: (\forall n\in\mathbb N)10^nx\not\in\mathbb Z\}$ ? That is, if you are interested in *notation*. If you are interested in something else, can you please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
$$S=\Bbb {(R-Q)}\cup\lbrace{x\in \Bbb Q|x={p\over q},\ \ p,q\in \Bbb Z, \ \ q\ne 
 0,\  \ (p,q)=1, \ \ \forall k\in\Bbb N, \ \ 10^k \ \  doesn't \ \ divide \  \   q}\rbrace \ \ $$

Comment: Although it does seem a bit of a long notation, it does suit my needs. Thank you!

Comment: That's kind of you!

Answer (score 0):

Your set includes all irrational numbers and all rational numbers whose simplified form is $m/n$ where $n$ has a  prime factor different from $2$ and $5$. For example $1/15$ is not in your set but $7/5$ is in your set.